# SQL Server 2005: When copy table structure to other database "CONSTRAINT" keywords lost

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup, copy, default-constraint

Snippet of original table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Batch](
    [CustomerDepositMade] [money] NOT NULL 
         CONSTRAINT [DF_Batch_CustomerDepositMade]  DEFAULT (0)
```

Snippet of copied table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Batch](
    [CustomerDepositMade] [money] NOT NULL,
```

Code for copy database:

```
        Server server = new Server(SourceSQLServer);
        Database database = server.Databases[SourceDatabase];

        Transfer transfer = new Transfer(database);
        transfer.CopyAllObjects = true;
        transfer.CopySchema = true;
        transfer.CopyData = false;

        transfer.DropDestinationObjectsFirst = true;

        transfer.DestinationServer = DestinationSQLServer;
        transfer.CreateTargetDatabase = true;

        Database ddatabase = new Database(server, DestinationDatabase);
        ddatabase.Create();
        transfer.DestinationDatabase = DestinationDatabase;
        transfer.Options.IncludeIfNotExists = true;
        transfer.TransferData();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Transfer.Options property may provide an answer.  In particular, looking at the  [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions.dridefaults(v=SQL.100).aspx), setting the DriDefaults property and, more generally, the DriAll property to true may help.